# How do I search a node with namespaces defined in the same node

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

If ancestor nodes defines namespaces, I can use them:

```
> Nokogiri::XML(<<-XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="2.0" unique-identifier="bookid">
  <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
    <dc:creator opf:role="aut">John Doe</dc:creator>
  </metadata>
</package>
XML
> xml.at_xpath("//dc:creator[@opf:role='aut']", xml.at_xpath("//xmlns:metadata").namespaces).text
 => "John Doe"
```

However, what shall I do with following XML?

```
> Nokogiri::XML(<<-XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="2.0" unique-identifier="bookid">
  <metadata>
    <dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" opf:role="aut">John Doe</dc:creator>
  </metadata>
</package>
XML
> xml.at_xpath("//dc:creator[@opf:role='aut']", xml.at_xpath("//xmlns:metadata").namespaces).text
Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError: Undefined namespace prefix: //dc:creator[@opf:role='aut']
```

I think `xml.remove_namespaces!` or literal namespace arguments for `at_xpath` is last resort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To programmatically collect all the namespaces, use `Document#collect_namespaces`.

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(xmldata)

ns = xml.collect_namespaces

puts xml.at('//dc:creator[@opf:role="aut"]', ns).text
```

Output:

```
John Doe
```

Comment: I know that we can specify namespaces literally if we know the namespaces beforehand, but how do I get those namespaces programmatically?

Comment: Thanks! I haven't noticed the method `Nokogiri::XML#collect_namespaces`.